# Pan and zoom toolbar issue - Matlab 2016a

Tags: matlab, zooming, matlab-guide

I added to a Matlab GUI  Pan and Zoom toolbars so I can move over the image presented in the axes.

After I mark a point (and adding coordinate text) and use the pan and/or zoom the marked text is shown outside the image Axes all over the GUI (it move as I pan and zoom).

The Axes, pan and zoom toolbar and the ui.figure 'Clipping' property is set to on.

There is no code as I use the toolbar and therefore how can it be solve?

Image example (White represent the outside of the Axes):
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some code or a screenshot demonstrating your issue?

Comment: If there's no code what is generating the coordinates?

Comment: Example ode of coordinates:  `code` stringX1Y1= horzcat(num2str(x1),', ',num2str(y1));
text(x1+2,y1-2, stringX1Y1, 'VerticalAlignment','middle', 'HorizontalAlignment','left','FontSize',10);

Comment: You could use a [listener](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) on changes to the axes limits that toggles visibility of the [`text` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) if they go outside the limits.

Comment: Why not create a [custom datatip](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/10/19/tutorial-how-to-make-a-custom-data-tip-in-matlab/) instead of adding `text` objects?

Comment: I wish to have a simple solution and not to add the data interactively. Is there a way to embedded them on the image?